# How to prevent Wordpress theme options page is saving blank fields?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So, I've been following a lot of tutorials on how to create a Wordpress theme options page, and I've gotten pretty far in the process. In fact, I'm virtually done, but there is one giant bug in my saving function.

If the option field is left blank, it saves the blank field to the database, so everything on the front-end is essentially blank.  When I click save in my options page, I want it to only update the fields that have information edited, and if the field is left blank, it removes the data from the database.

Here is my saving script:

```
if ( $_GET['page'] == basename(__FILE__) ) {

    if ( 'save' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {

        foreach ($options as $value) {
        update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ); }

foreach ($options as $value) {
    if( isset( $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ) ) { update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ]  ); } else { delete_option( $value['id'] ); } }

    header("Location: admin.php?page=admin-panel.php&saved=true");
die;

}
```

That script is pulling the ID from an options array. On example would be for the logo:

```
array( "name" => "Logo URL",
        "desc" => "Enter the link to your logo image",
        "id" => $shortname."_logo",
        "type" => "text",
        "std" => ""),
```

So with the logo example above, if I enter something in the Logo URL field, it updates it fine and it appears on the front-end, but if I leave it blank, and hit save, it updates the database with a blank value, so nothing appears on the front-end, not even the default value.

Any ideas on how I can update the saving script to prevent this?

Comment: what do you want to do if 'id' is blank?

Comment: I guess if it is blank or the user removes what's inside the field, I want it to remove the field from the database.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested that may have viewed a similar tutorial, removing the `isset` portion of the script solves the problem!